# Parse Configuration File C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I need some help with parsing a text file that contains multiple sections. The file is in the following format:

```
;This is a comment that should be ignored when parsing 

;Colors in 24-bit format
#define BLUE 16711680
#define RED 255

[SETTINGS]
File Name
File Description
v1.0

[SECTION]
BLUE  N033.56.09.699 W118.25.09.714

[SECTION2]
RED    N033.56.13.675 W118.24.30.908
       N033.56.13.675 W118.24.30.908
       N033.56.16.034 W118.24.07.905
```

Basically, I need to skip any comments. I also need to be able to pull the child value from the #define section. Lastly, I need to parse each line under each header section (e.g. `[SETTINGS]`, `[SECTION]`, etc). The file is not just limited to these headers.

Here's what I have now, but it obviously doesn't work.

```
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] items = line.Split('\t');
    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        if(item.StartsWith("[SETTINGS]"))
        {

        }
        if(item.StartsWith("[SECTIOn]"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a app.config or web.config file with `<appSettings>`?  Maybe even a custom configuration section?

Comment: @Tim, short answer: no. This is because the config file that needs to be parsed is imported by the end user, so there can be different variations of config data.

Comment: What about the variables in the '#define' section, do they carry the same format of a key value pair, as in `#define `][ `KEY` ][ `VALUE`

Comment: I should have been more clear, but yes, the #define has both a key and value.

Comment: I am going to shamelessly plug my own software here. Check out my [TokenIcer project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220042/Easily-Create-Your-Own-Parser). It can help you with this.

Comment: [SECTION2] is different from [SECTION] by the fact that red is only on the first line, is that difference to be expected?

Comment: Since things have multiple lines you are going to have to code this as a state machine--when you see a header line you note what section you are in and use the appropriate parsing code.

Comment: As Tim pointed out, it would be best to use a .Net standard. Otherwise, existing tools like the one @icemanind pointed out might also be a better starting point than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Instead of splitting each line by Tabs and looping, use line.Trim(); to remove the white space, so you can do line.StartsWith or Regex to get the values.

Comment: I understand you cannot use app.config or web.config, but can you use XML instead of that format?  Are you in control of the format?  If so then this gets easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the type of data structure you wanted, you can use the code below....

[image: This is what the result will pretty much look like]

```
void Main()
{
    // Gets rid of any comments that exist in our config file
    IEnumerable<string> textLines = text.Split('\n')
                                        .Where(line => !line.StartsWith(";"));;

    // Converts our 'IEnumerable<string> textLines' back to a string without comments
    string textWithoutComments = string.Join("\n", textLines);

    // Retrieves which variables are defined
    // >> BLUE 16711680 
    // >> RED 255 
    Dictionary<string, string> definedVariables = textLines .Where(line => line.StartsWith(@"#define"))
                                                            .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, @"#define ([^ ]*) (.*)"))
                                                            .ToDictionary(match => match.Groups[1].Value, match => match.Groups[2].Value);

    // Creates a dictionary of sections that have been defined
    // >> SETTINGS      File Name
    // >>               File Description
    // >>               v1.0
    // >>
    // >> SECTION BLUE  N033.56.09.699 W118.25.09.714
    // >>
    // >> SECTION2 RED  N033.56.13.675 W118.24.30.908
    // >>               N033.56.13.675 W118.24.30.908
    // >>               N033.56.16.034 W118.24.07.905 
    Dictionary<string, string> sectionDictionary = Regex.Matches(textWithoutComments, @"\[([\w]*)\]\n([^\[^\#]*)")
                                                        .Cast<Match>()
                                                        .ToDictionary(match => match.Groups[1].Value, match => match.Groups[2].Value);


    UserConfiguration userConfig = new UserConfiguration 
    {
        Variables = definedVariables,
        Settings  = sectionDictionary["SETTINGS"],
        Sections  = sectionDictionary.Where(dictionary  => dictionary.Key != "SETTINGS")
                                    .Select(dictionary  => new {Key = dictionary.Key, Value = Regex.Match(dictionary.Value, @"(\w*) ([^\[]*)")})
                                    .ToDictionary(anon => anon.Key, anon => new Config 
                                    { 
                                        Name = anon.Value.Groups[1].Value, 
                                        Value = anon.Value.Groups[2].Value.RemoveWhiteSpace()
                                    })
    };

}
public class UserConfiguration
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Variables { get; set; }
    public string Settings { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Config> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Config
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string RemoveWhiteSpace(this string text)
    {
        var lines = text.Split('\n');
        return string.Join("\n", lines.Select(str => str.Trim()));
    }
}

const string text = @";This is a comment that should be ignored when parsing 

;Colors in 24-bit format
#define BLUE 16711680
#define RED 255

[SETTINGS]
File Name
File Description
v1.0

[SECTION]
BLUE  N033.56.09.699 W118.25.09.714

[SECTION2]
RED    N033.56.13.675 W118.24.30.908
    N033.56.13.675 W118.24.30.908
    N033.56.16.034 W118.24.07.905";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel like testing it but here is a start:

```
string line;
Dictionary Define<string, int> = new Dictionary<string, int>();

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   if(line.StartsWith(";"))
   {
      continue;
   }

   if(line.StartsWith("#define")
   {
      string[] defineItems = line.Split();
      Define[defineItems[1]] = defineItems[2];
      continue;
   }

   if(line.StartsWith("[SETTINGS]"))
        {

        }
        if(item.StartsWith("[SECTIOn]"))
        {

        }

}
```

Comment: Since it is reading line-by-line, I'm curious how you would associate "File Name" with "[SETTINGS]" in this code example.

Answer (score 0):

I made the sections different actions in a dictionary to allow for readability - as you start adding sections the  `if` statement will just grow into a maintainability nightmare. I tested using a console, so this is a bit unpolished code-wise. In a nutshell:

See if the record is a `#definition` record, if it is, split it into a name and value string set.

If the record is a code comment record, skip.

If the record starts with anything in the dictionary keys, update the current section to that. So when you see `[Settings]`, the current action will be `UpdateSettingsConfiguration` and when you see `[Section]`, the current action will be `UpdateSectionConfiguration`.

When a record isn't a comment, a `#definition` record, or a section header, it will call the Action that applies to the most recently defined section header and allow that to process. This can also be handy in case users are naughty and define `[Settings]` in multiple places in the file.

```
class Program {
    private const string ConfigComment = ";";
    private const string ConfigDefine = "#define";
    private static readonly KeyValuePair<string, Action<string>> DefaultActionValuePair = new KeyValuePair<string, Action<string>>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Action<string>> settingSection = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>(){
            { "[SETTINGS]", UpdateSettingsConfiguration}
            { "[Section]", UpdateSectionConfiguration}
        };
    static void Main() {

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt");
        string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        Action<string> currentSection = null;
        do {
            if (currentLine.StartsWith(ConfigDefine)) { //Definitions are used different than the rest of the config file, handle them special.
                string[] definition = currentLine.Substring(ConfigDefine.Length + 1).Split(' ');

                AddDefinitions(definition[0], definition[1]);
            } else if (!currentLine.StartsWith(ConfigComment)) {

                var kvp =
                    settingSection.FirstOrDefault(
                        x => x.Key.StartsWith(currentLine, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                if (kvp.Equals(DefaultActionValuePair)) {


                    if (currentSection == null) {
                        //Invalid setting
                    } else {
                        currentSection(currentLine);
                    }
                } else {
                    currentSection = kvp.Value;
                }
            }
            currentLine = reader.ReadLine();

        } while (!reader.EndOfStream);
    }

    private static void AddDefinitions(string p1, string p2) {
        //Do stuff here
    }

    static void UpdateSettingsConfiguration(string setting) {
        //do stuff here
    }
    static void UpdateSectionConfiguration(string setting) {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```